# How to do SSH tunnelling from Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, ssh, tunnel

For a C#/.NET 4.0 worker app running on Windows Azure, I would like to setup *on demand* SSH tunnels to 3rd party servers (mostly to access secure MySQL databases). [SSH.NET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) is an open-source project precisely designed to open SSH tunnels from .NET. However, I am concerned about the local port allocation.

Has anyone ever succeeded in establishing a SSH Tunnel from Windows Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Establishing SSH Tunnel is simple - just set up port 22 SSH endpoint on your Azure VM. Your public port doesnt have to be 22, but the private port has to be.

From your Azure dashboard of your VM, click on 'Endpoints' and 'Add' - Choose SSH and port 22.

If your VM is non linux, say you're using Windows, then you might need to [install a SSH server](http://www.syncplify.me/download.html).

Answer (score 0):

using a putty client install, yes. windows firewall is under your control. what else would stand in your way?